# Image Views inside Relative Layout behaving differently in 2 different layout files

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-view, android-relativelayout

search_36.png image is behaving differently inside both layout files.

Both the **search_36.png** images used are same file with 36x36 pixels inside drawable-xhdpi folder.

This is my first layout file nav_draw_list_row.xml
http://www.use.com/CqAhJ
In this when i use match parent height for image search_36 image view. The image is not stretched...But the layout is stretched to match parent's height.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="48dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/listItemImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/search_36"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/listItemTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="ABCDE"/>
```

While in the second layout fragment_navigation_drawer.xml layout the image **search_36**  is stretched with the layout when i use match parent for height....
I cant figure out why...    http://www.use.com/CqAjz
Any help is appreciated..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="280dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/primaryColor"
tools:context="stockquote.anirudh.com.stockquote.NavigationDrawerFragment">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/abstractimage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/abstract_image_margin_top"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_abstract_blue" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/stockSearchLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/abstractimage"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageSearch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/search_36" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchStockTextViewNav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:hint="@string/stock_hint"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/deleteStockImageButtonNav"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/cancel_36" />

</RelativeLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/lineView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/stockSearchLinearLayout"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@color/white"></View>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/navListView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lineView"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:entries="@array/nav_Draw_List" />
```

Answer (score 0):

On the second layout, you have the drawable set as the background, which causes it to stretch to fit the view:

```
android:background="@drawable/search_36"
```

Set it to the src to match the first layout:

```
android:src="@drawable/search_36"
```